# Increase column length of Acumatica field to nvarchar(max)

Tags: acumatica

I want to increase the column length of a standard Acumatica field from nvchar(1000) to nvarchar(max), but not sure about how to do this. I tried to use the column length increase but it does not allow entering MAX. I tried the below, but it resulted in ntext rather than nvarchar(max).

```
<Column TableName="SMEmail" ColumnName="MailBcc" ColumnType="string" AllowNull="True" DecimalPrecision="0" DecimalLength="0" IsUnicode="True" />
```

ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server, therefore it's best not to use these.

The other option I am thinking is to use a DDL script to Alter the column, but I would have preferred to do it using standard Acumatica functionality instead. Is there a way to do it without executing an Alter script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Customization Project Editor tool engine won't allow you to set 'MAX'.
The maximum value allowed in the Customization Project Editor tool engine is '4000'.
So you could use this '4000' value instead.